# Why does the global variable gets value NaN? Solved Thank you Everyone

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    let rectX = 0 ;
    let rectY = 0;
    let secondsPassed = 0;
    let timeStamp = 0
    let oldTimeStamp = 0;
    let movingSpeed = 50;
    gameLoop()
    function draw() {
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 150, 100);
    }

    function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
        // Calculate how much time has passed
        secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
        oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
        update(secondsPassed);
        draw();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }

    function update(secondsPassed) {
        rectX += (movingSpeed * secondsPassed);
        rectY += (movingSpeed * secondsPassed);
    }
```

rectX and rectY initially have a number value, movingSpeed also has a number value, secondsPassed as well.My question is why the function "update" gives NaN to the variables rectX and rectY ? No errors are shown in console. I tried to log and used typeof to check if every variable had a value with a  type number and I noticed that rectX is once considered a string, I tried to parseFloat the rectX but still it was giving me NaN. Normally, we use timeStamp to return a value that can help us calculate the fps. In this case I'm using timeStamp to see how many seconds have passed before running the function gameLoop. I'm doing this because it's no longer the frame rate (and hardware) that decides the speed of the game, but it's time.

**Update: is solved thanks to
@epascarello, @James and @Kaiido. There's the updated code for you guys:**

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas')
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    let rectX = 0;
    let rectY = 0;
    let secondsPassed = 0;
    let oldTimeStamp = 0;
    let timeStamp = 0
    let movingSpeed = 50;
    let timePassed = 0
    function draw() {
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 150, 100);
    }

    function gameLoop(timeStamp) {
        // Calculate how much time has passed
        secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
        oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;

        // Pass the time to the update
        update(secondsPassed);
        draw();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(function(timeStamp){gameLoop(timeStamp)});
    }

    function update(secondsPassed) {
        // Use time to calculate new position
        rectX += (movingSpeed * secondsPassed);
        rectY += (movingSpeed * secondsPassed);
        
        
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(timeStamp){gameLoop(timeStamp)});
```

Comment: Add console.log() and see what is NaN

Comment: `rectX` and `rextY` are `undefined` initially.

Comment: and because you never pass in `timeStamp` Look at `gameLoop()` <---- and --->  `function gameLoop(timeStamp) {` simple console.log() with variables would have let you see that.

Comment: You dont have a default value for these variables. `let rectX;` is undefined by default unless u assign something to it and `undefined += number` is `NaN`

Comment: but still if i give a value to rectX or rectY it will give NaN

Comment: what is `timeStamp` supposed to be?  It's currently undefined, which will make oldTimestamp undefined, which will make secondsPassed NaN, which will break rectX and rectY.

Comment: timeStamp returns a value that can be used to get the value of fps. In this case I'm using timeStamp to see how many seconds have passed before running the function gameLoop. I'm going to be updating my question and sorry for not being so specific. I'm doing this because it's no longer the frame rate (and hardware) that decides the speed of the game, but it's time.

Comment: Call your first `gameLoop` from `requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)` too, or initialise `timestamp` to document.timeline.currentTime

Comment: Thank you everyone. I've called window.requestAnimationFrame((timeStamp) => {this.gameLoop(timeStamp)}) and it worked

Answer (score 1):

your problem is `let rectX;` in line 3 creates an "undefined"

if you use `rectX += 1` js tries to add undefined + 1 (automaticly string converting from undefined)

sting + int = NaN

```js
let rectX = 0;
let rectY = 0;
let speed = 1;
function update(seconds){
  rectX += (speed * seconds);
  rectY += (speed * seconds);
}

// test:

update(5);
console.log(rectX, rectY); // output is 5 5
```

Comment: Still will be NaN with just that fix

Comment: it's not a fix, it's the description why this wont work. `let rectX = 0; rextX += 1;` this is a hint to a fix

Comment: And typically answers state how to fix it and fixing this one issue is still going to have NaN

Comment: `string + int = longer string`

Comment: but still if i give a value to rectX or rectY it will give NaN.

Comment: edited my answer with a working sample

Comment: I already updated my code with rectX = 0 and rectY = 0, but still NaN

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not passing timeStamp into the gameLoop function when you call it initially.  inside gameLoop, `timeStamp` is undefined, which breaks the other variables.

You could pass in the current time stamp when you first call it.  Instead of
`gameLoop()` try

```
gameLoop(Date.now().getTime())
```

Comment: They are using requestAnimationFrame, which passes a DOMHighResTimestamp (basically the number of ms since the doc is alive) so the timestamp they'll get in the second frame will be something around 17ms, `Date.now().getTime()` will return the number of ms since 1970/01/01, so something around 1.6 **Trillions** ms.  Let's say they expect their animation speed to be something like 1px per frame on most common monitors (60Hz), that's a jump of -1e12px at the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

intitialing the variable rectX and rectY might help.

try this:

```
rectX = 0;
rectY = 0;
```

Comment: but still if i give a value to rectX or rectY it will give NaN

Comment: See the comments from @epascarello above. (1) timestamp is also uninitialized and therefore so is secondsPassed, (2) log / or inspect the inputs to expressions that give you unexpected results.

Comment: I've already done that, tried to log everything, I used typeof to see if it was a string or a number but still gave me NaN. So strange, I will try to log the inputs one more time

Comment: All that debug info should be in the question, @Tomasnborges

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. I will be updating my question.